# MacBook Pro kernel panic after speaker change

Tags: audio, crash, kernel-panic, driver

I have recently changed the speakers of my 13" retina MacBook Pro(Mid 2014, MacOS Sierra) and after few days my Macbook crashed while scanning a document using an HP printer which was connected via USB cable. It was not responding to the power button. I went to apple service center, there they removed the connection of battery from the motherboard. Afer that MacBook started responding to the power button. But it is not working as it used to. It is repeatedly restarting without any warning and display is flickering.

When I start MacBook in Safe Mode it works really well. So, I looked at panic logs. I can see after loading *com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC* while booting MacBook restarted. In safe mode the sound is not enabled and it is working well without any problem, so I think, and please correct me if I am wrong, the problem lies in AudioAUUC. Is there any way I force MacOS to not load these problematic drivers while booting normally? Any help is really appreciated.

Please find part of panic logs below:

```
Mac OS version:
16F73

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 16.6.0: Fri Apr 14 16:21:16 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.60.24~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FB2170A8-257D-3C64-B14D-BC06CC94E34C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000012600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8012800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8012700000
System model name: MacBookPro11,1 (Mac-189A3D4F975D5FFC)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 24172689777
last loaded kext at 12185909650: com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.70 (addr 0xffffff7f956b8000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
....
```

Comment: Have you tried an [SMC reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) after having the service done?

Comment: Yes I have. I tried SMC reset. I even installed Yosemite still the same problem. Then I upgraded to Sierra again.

Comment: The problem here is that your USB is totally separate from audio.  Changing a speaker in a MBP is like switching the speakers on your home stereo from Boston Acoustics to Bose (you don't need a new amp to drive them).  Running in safe mode disables a bunch of other things, that could *also* be conflicting; audio may just be a coincidence.  Have you tried a *clean* install (on a USB drive)?

Comment: Thanks, Allan. To isolate the problem, it is necessary for me to install driver one by one and check what causes the problem. As I did not find any simple way to do that in MacOS, So I have installed Windows 10 on MBP.  Before installing any drivers windows was running correctly, as soon as I installed drivers present in Bootcamp, Windows 10 showed the same behavior which MacOS was showing, i.e, the display is flickering and it is restarting repeatedly.  After few attempt looks like when Intel Iris Graphics driver is loaded, Macbook crashes. Not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I needed to find out a way to install drivers one by one to see what causes the display to flicker and OS to crash. I did not a find an easy way to do this in Mac OS. So I installed [Windows 10 on MacBook Pro without using Bootcamp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0OEpg-yb10). I downloaded Bootcamp support software from Apple website. I did not install all drivers from this support software at once. Instead, I installed drivers one by one and verified if it is causing any problem. After hours of investigation, I found out that as soon as Intel Iris Device Driver is installed operating system crashes. To get MacBook working again, I had to find a way in which I could force operating system from loading these device drivers. Even if I do not install these drivers manually, windows would download drivers and install it for me. To make sure windows do not download these drivers, I did three things.

First, I made sure [windows will not install drivers for the faulty hardware.](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/06/03/stop-windows-from-installing-drivers-for-specific-devices/) 
Second, I disabled automatic driver download and install.
Third, I changed my wifi connection to metered.

Now everything is working. But I am using Windows 10 instead of MacOS. Windows 10 saved me from replacing logic board on my MacBook Pro. Windows 10 supports bash, so I feel at home.